# Is there a detailed specification for Outlook 365 IMAP? Which RFC's does it comply with?

Tags: outlook, imap

Does anyone know if there is a specification for Outlook 365 that would describe their IMAP implementation in detail.

In particular, Which RFC's they comply with.  For example, there are many Updates to RFC 3501.  RFC 3501 list these RFC's in the update section. 466, 4469, 4551, 5032, 5182, 5738,6186, 6858, 7817, 8314, 8437, 8474

In addition, I'm having problems with how Outlook manages IMAP folder's. Outlook is sending the LIST command but not the LSUB command.  LSUB is only send manually if the IMAP Folders outlook option is used. This is different from how other IMAP clients work.

Comment: I found a document that lists IMAP standards in outlook -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_standards/ms-stanoimap/9e26aea5-bb27-40d2-be9a-c82878c7d567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 365, like all IMAP servers, advertises its extensions when you connect to it. Here's an example where I send the `capability` command to ask it:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -crlf
[…]
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [Zm5vcmQK]
a capability
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
a OK CAPABILITY completed.
```

The server almost certainly advertises more extensions after login. The IANA maintains a [map from capability name to RFC](https://www.iana.org/assignments/imap-capabilities/imap-capabilities.xml).

Answer (score 0):

I found that this document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_standards/ms-stanoimap/9e26aea5-bb27-40d2-be9a-c82878c7d567

Provides the best spec for how outlook imap differs from the standard.

I found that Outlook requires the XLIST command to be used in place of the LSUB for folders to be displayed. This is strange since XLISt its NOT listed in the CAPABILITIES string.

Comment: XLIST has been superseded by [6154](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6154) and IIRC O365 was updated years ago.

Comment: I attempted to convert my LIST to use the (SPECIAL-USE) syntax in 6154, but outlook did not respond.  I also don't see any mention that Outlook makes use of 6154.  in [MS-STANOIMAP]: Outlook Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP) Standards Support